# How to increment a field in MySql using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" when inserting multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

How to increment a field in MySql using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" when inserting multiple rows?

For one row:

```
INSERT INTO table 
  (a, counter_elem) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter_elem = counter_elem+1;
```

For multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO table 
  (a, counter_elem) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter_elem = ?;
```

This doesn't work:

```
counter_elem = VALUES(counter_elem)+1
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Exactly the same way!

```
INSERT INTO table 
  (a, counter_elem) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter_elem = counter_elem + 1;
```

There's no problem there!

Comment: You're right. I tried it before asking my question but it produced wrong increment because of a bug in my class, now I fixed the bug and it works.