# use insert if unique constraint but use update on duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

i have this table called **inventory** 
*chara_id, item_id and item_level* are one unique constraint

```
+--------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
| inventory_id | chara_id | item_id | item_level | item_qty |
+--------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
|           35 |        1 |       2 |          0 |        3 |
|           37 |        1 |      14 |          0 |        1 |
|           46 |        4 |       4 |          0 |        1 |
|           49 |        1 |       3 |          0 |        1 |
|           66 |       16 |       6 |          0 |        1 |
|           67 |       16 |       1 |          0 |        1 |
|           75 |       17 |       3 |          0 |        1 |
|           78 |       15 |       2 |          0 |        1 |
|           86 |       12 |       3 |          0 |        2 |
|           88 |       12 |       1 |          0 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

and i have this second table called **equipment**

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| equip_id | chara_id | weapon_id | headgear_id | armor_id | ring_id | weapon_level | headgear_level | armor_level | ring_level |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
|        1 |        1 |         2 |          16 |       18 |      17 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        2 |        2 |         2 |           5 |        6 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        3 |        3 |         0 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        4 |        4 |         2 |           5 |        6 |       8 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        5 |        5 |         0 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        6 |        6 |         0 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        7 |        7 |         0 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        8 |        8 |         0 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|        9 |        9 |         4 |           0 |        0 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
|       10 |       10 |        12 |           5 |       18 |       0 |            0 |              0 |           0 |          0 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

**what i want is:**
when i 
`insert into inventory(chara_id,item_id,item_level,item_qty)values(1,2,2,1)`

this will insert another entry in my table
otherwise when i insert:
`insert into inventory(chara_id,item_id,item_level,item_qty)values(1,2,0,1)`
it will update the `item_qty = item_qty + 1` which is the first row in my inventory table above.
 kudos guyz

Comment: Look into MySQL's `insert ignore`, `replace` and `insert ... on duplicate key update` statements.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment a field in MySql using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" when inserting multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802239/how-to-increment-a-field-in-mysql-using-on-duplicate-key-update-when-inserting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `chara_id, item_id and item_level` constitute a `UNIQUE` index then use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` like this

```
INSERT INTO inventory(chara_id,item_id,item_level,item_qty) 
VALUES(1,2,2,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_qty = item_qty + VALUES(item_qty);

INSERT INTO inventory(chara_id,item_id,item_level,item_qty) 
VALUES(1,2,0,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_qty = item_qty + VALUES(item_qty);
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae31f/1)** demo

Comment: i learned yet another mysql combo there, i didnt know you can put VALUES(item_qty) as a replacement for +1, and it more flexible since i can increment it any values i want, kudos sir