# How to increment a field in MySql using “ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” when each row increment each value?

Tags: mysql, sql

this question like [increment a field with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802239/how-to-increment-a-field-in-mysql-using-on-duplicate-key-update-when-inserting/37809224#37809224) 
but I want to achieve each row increment each value

for example:
a is a primary key

```
Original data
a   | share_count | read_count |
1   |     2       |     3      |

through
INSERT INTO table (a, share_count,read_count)
VALUES(1,share_count+1,read_count+2),(2,share_count+2,read_count+3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
a=VALUES(a),share_count=VALUES(share_count),read_count=VALUES(read_count)

Goal result
a   | share_count | read_count |
1   |     3       |     5      |
2   |     2       |     3      |
```

I tried,but fail.Thanks for answering

Comment: Can you provide sample data and explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you try to `INSERT` you insert `count=1` but not `share_count+2` or `read_count+3`.

If I guess your goal correctly you need something like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d4c6/1

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a, share_count,read_count)
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
share_count=share_count+1,read_count=read_count+1
```